# How to check if a file is present in a ZIP folder using Command Prompt?

Tags: cmd, zip

I want to check if main.lua is present in a ZIP Folder before trying to extract it. Also, I use 7-zip for archive things in command prompt. I have something like this, but I want to know if it can be simplified:

```
if exist "%temp\main.lua" (
del "%temp\main.lua"
)
7z e "(ZIP Folder)" "-o%temp%"
if exist "%temp\main.lua" (
rem main.lua is present in the ZIP folder.
) else (
rem main.lua is NOT present in the ZIP folder.
)
```

I would actually prefer a VBScript doing it since not everyone has 7-zip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of extracting the zip, why not just use the list command (l) to see if the file is present or not. So you could do something like this:

```
set mainfound=0
7z l zipname.zip | findstr /r /c:" main.lua$" >nul && set mainfound=1
```

And then you can test the value of `%mainfound%` to determine whether *main.lua* was found or not.

I'm using a regex search to make sure there is a space before the filename and it ends at the end of the line (the `$` in the regex). That way we don't get false positives from partial matches.

Comment: Thanks! I knew there was a list command in 7-zip, I just never knew there was a findstr command in Command Prompt.

Comment: About the regex, it returns true if the file name is ___ main.lua so I replace the regex with ^....-..-.. ..:..:.. ..... ............ ............  main.lua$". I just don't know if the same format will work with older versions of 7-zip.

Comment: I wonder if `[0-9]  main\.lua$` may be good enough? At least one digit (from the file size), two spaces, and then the name. What are the chances of having a filename with two spaces in the name? Also note the `.` in the filename needs to be escaped with a backslash otherwise it will match anything - I forgot that in my original answer.